# why I am getting template string expression error?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am making a dark mode in react and passing the state as a prop in a component but its giving an error.

I tried putting code under different situations but got no success

here is the code in which I am getting error

`<nav className={'navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-${props.mode} bg-${props.mode}'}>`

that's what I am getitng 
Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string

Comment: Wrong quote character for template strings. `"\`"`

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković Thanks it works I literally didn't see that. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already given. I'll not repeat.

Still I'll give you this suggestion, you can use ternary operator to render className based on the props.mode value:

```
<nav className={`navbar navbar-expand-lg ${props.mode === 'light' ? 'navbar-light bg-light' : 'navbar-dark bg-dark'}`}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting errors because you are using single quotes `''` instead of backticks ``` `` ``` ,
your code should look like this:

```
<nav className={`navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-${props.mode} bg-${props.mode}`}>
```